# Scaling down Stroked lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, scale

I have several lines and arcs with different Strokes and want to scale down all objects similarly. When I select and Shift+Drag, all objects scaled down but lines Strokes. How can I change scale of the strokes?

Answer (score 1):

Tick **Scale Strokes And Effects** on the **Transform Panel** before dragging.

<sub>(Scale Strokes and Effects is also in the Preferences, but the Transform Panel is easier.)</sub>